# Need UPS communication software for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, ups

I have a server that should have an energy backup. I want to use some UPS for this.

How to make it can communicate with PC, so it can makes the PC shutdown automatically?

Whats software for communicate UPS with Linux Ubuntu PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Ubuntu repositories there's [`upsd`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/upsd) and [`apcupsd`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/apcupsd).

[`man upsd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/upsd.8.html)

[`man apcupsd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/apcupsd.8.html)

Comment: what is the different of both?

Comment: `apcupsd` is for APC brand UPSs. `upsd` is for any compatible serial-port UPS.

Answer (score 2):

NUT is also a useful UPS package. It's also flexible configured to monitor remotely and to monitor multiple UPSes and shut down multiple servers in a network.

Its drawback is that it can be difficult to set up properly. Single systems with one attached UPS can be set up fairly easily, as long as you pay careful attention to the instructions.

More information is available at http://www.networkupstools.org.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of gnome-power-manager have support for certain brands of UPS and expose shutdown options via its preferences.